# Parsing a string of XML in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I know there's a ton of documentation on this, but I just can't get it. I've been looking for awhile and I'd like to get some help on my specific situation to shed some light on this.

I used an Http Client to get a string of XML that reads:

```
<groups>
<group>
    <id>35</id>
    <sport>Racing</sport>
    <name>Indianapolis 500</name>
    <date>27/4/2012</date>
    <time>12:00</time>
    <period>PM</period>
    <location>Indiana</location>
</group>
<group>
    <id>36</id>
    <sport>Baseball</sport>
    <name>Miami Heat game</name>
    <date>27/4/2012</date>
    <time>3:00</time>
    <period>PM</period>
    <location>Miami, FL</location>
</group>
</groups>
```

I have another class called XMLParser with method called takeNameGetID, it takes the whole string of XML and a string of the name it's looking for in a `<name>` and should attempt to find the "block" that has that name and returns the corresponding `<id>` as an integer. That is what confuses me.

```
public int takeNamegetID(String name, String allXML) {
    //This is what I can't figure out
}
```

I'm calling it in the first class like so:

```
XMLparser parser = new XMLparser();
int actualId = parser.takeNamegetID(getGroupString(), getGroupXML());
```

The two methods, `getGroupString()` and `getGroupsXML()` are rather self explanatory. One gets the name it's looking for as a string and the other gets the entire XML, respectively.

What I need is an example or someone to show me the implementation of the takeNamegetID method that I want. I've been looking forever and I think it's best if I just ask for my specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: XML parsing in Java is verbose, particularly on Android (where third-party parsers may or may not work). Expecting somebody to write your code for you may be a bit much. That being said, you can use SAX (http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicSax.html) or the DOM (http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicDom.html) or the `XmlPullParser` (http://xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html). The first two have been in Java for ages and are covered in many books and blog posts.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense as to why I was having so much trouble. I just thought I was missing something but I guess it really is that complex. I'll give it another try with the first SAX you gave me. Is that built into Android or Java or will I have to import some external package or something to use it?

Comment: All three of the solutions I cited in my comment are built into Android.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use SimpleXML(http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php), I have used it in two android projects, it is small and easy to use.

java code:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class Group {
@Element
private int id;
@Element
private String sport;
@Element
...

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
...
}


import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;    
import org.simpleframework.xml.*   

public class Groups {
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private List<Group> group;

    public List<Group> getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(List<Group> group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        Groups groups = serializer.read(Groups.class, your_xml_inputstream);
        System.out.println(groups.getGroup().size());
    }
}
```